# Devise authenticates before user/<id> but I want to turn it off

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've got Devise working on my Ruby on Rails application but viewing the user requires authentication and I don't want that. I've tried setting authenticate_user like so:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  ..
end
```

But it still redirects to the sign_in page. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Rim
PS: Please excuse my n00b-ness

Comment: Seems strange, that should work fine!

Comment: @ant yeah it was me being dumb... I been working too many hours.

Comment: Haha I know the feeling!

Answer (score 0):

Doh!

I was getting confused and had the wrong path. I been scratching my head for ages on that.

I fixed it...

Answer (score -1):

I always use to copy controller files from devise gem folder to my applications controller folder

The devise controller files can be found here /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.1.2/app/controllers/ (may be at different location in your case)

Copy devise folder in there and paste it to app/controllers/ and then customize registrations_controller as per your need

But I believe there must be some good solution on this. By the time you can use this.. :)